JMX Exporter Fails to Scrape Kafka Broker Metrics in Docker on Azure - Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: Connection refused to localhost
I’m running Kafka in Docker on an Azure virtual machine (VM) with JMX enabled, and I’m trying to scrape Kafka broker metrics using JMX Exporter. However, while jmxterm works perfectly and lists all the MBeans, JMX Exporter fails with the following error:

SEVERE: JMX scrape failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve
RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root
exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
localhost; nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection
refused]

Setup Details:
Azure VM:
Running Ubuntu on Azure.
Kafka and JMX Exporter are running as Docker containers using network_mode: host.
Firewall rules are configured to allow traffic on the JMX ports (both 9102 and 9103).
Question:
Why does jmxterm work but JMX Exporter fails to scrape the metrics? Is there a way for JMX Exporter to bypass the RMI stub and fetch the beans directly like jmxterm? How can I ensure the RMI stub advertises the correct hostname when running Kafka in Docker on Azure?
Kafka Broker:
Running in a Docker container with network_mode: host.
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS are configured as follows:
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9102 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9102 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.port=9102 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<Public IP of Azure VM>\
                -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
                -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=VERBOSE"

JMX Exporter:
Running in another Docker container with the following docker-compose.yml setup
services:
  jmx-exporter:
    network_mode: host
    container_name: jmx-exporter
    image: bitnami/jmx-exporter:latest
    volumes:
      - ./config.yml:/opt/bitnami/jmx-exporter/config.yml

The config.yml contains the following:
startDelaySeconds: 0
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
ssl: false
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<Public IP of Azure VM>:9102/jmxrmi
hostPort: <Public IP of Azure VM>:9102
rules:
  - pattern: ".*"

What I’ve Tried:

jmxterm works fine when connecting to the JMX URL
(service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<Public IP of Azure VM>:9102/jmxrmi). It
successfully lists all the MBeans.
I’ve tested connectivity using nc from within the JMX Exporter
container, and connections to both localhost and  on
port 9102 are successful.
I’ve tried separating the RMI and JMX ports by setting different
ports (9102 for JMX and 9103 for RMI), but the issue persists.
RMI verbose logging is enabled
(-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=VERBOSE), and I can see logs that
indicate the Kafka broker is listening on the expected ports.

Logs from Kafka:
Here’s an excerpt from the Kafka logs when JMX starts:
> broker-1  | FINE: main: localHostKnown = true, localHost =
> <Public IP of Azure VM>broker-1  | FINE: RMI TCP Accept-9102: listening on port 9102

Kafka broker startup logs (related to JMX)
> broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef <init>
> broker-1  | FINE: main: localHostKnown = true, localHost = <Public IP
> of Azure VM> broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint broker-1  | FINE:
> main: Version = 2, ep = [<Public IP of Azure VM>:9102] broker-1  | Oct
> 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint
> broker-1  | FINE: main: created local endpoint for socket factory null
> on port 9102 broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint broker-1  | FINE:
> main: Version = 2, ep = [<Public IP of Azure VM>:0] broker-1  | Oct
> 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint
> broker-1  | FINE: main: created local endpoint for socket factory null
> on port 0 broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport exportObject broker-1  | FINE:
> main: (port 9102) create server socket broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024
> 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport listen broker-1  |
> FINER: main: creating server socket on [<Public IP of Azure VM>:9102]
> broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop run broker-1  | FINE:
> RMI TCP Accept-9102: listening on port 9102 broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024
> 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint broker-1
> | FINE: main: Version = 2, ep = [<Public IP of Azure
> VM>:0,sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory@43bc63a3]
> broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef <init>
> broker-1  | FINE: main: created local endpoint for socket factory
> sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory@43bc63a3 on port
> 0 broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport exportObject broker-1  | FINE:
> main: (port 0) create server socket broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21
> PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport listen broker-1  | FINER: main:
> creating server socket on [<Public IP of Azure
> VM>:0,sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory@43bc63a3]
> broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint
> newServerSocket broker-1  | FINE: main: default port for server socket
> factory sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory@43bc63a3
> and client socket factory null set to 46039 broker-1  | Oct 08, 2024
> 4:24:21 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop run broker-1 
> | FINE: RMI TCP Accept-0: listening on port 46039

The Problem:
Despite everything looking good in jmxterm and the connectivity checks working, JMX Exporter still fails to scrape metrics due to Connection refused to host: localhost. This suggests that the RMI stub might still be advertising localhost instead of <Public IP of Azure VM>, but I’ve already set the java.rmi.server.hostname to <Public IP of Azure VM>.

Do other Java services work with this config? It sounds like an exporter / prometheus issue rather than Kafka specifically... If you run Strimzi on AKS instead of Docker, then JMX exporter use builtin

As I meantioned, JMXterm works fine with this kafka config. But I have understood that JMXterm does not use RMI and directly connects to jmx port to fetch the beans. But jmx exporter works with RMI first and then gets the beans. And, the problem is happening with this RMI

And you need to use Docker (Compose) on a VM instead of AKS / Kubernetes?

yes. I want to install jmxExporter using docker on Azure VM and make it export jmx beans from Kafka brokers.. this metrics will be then scraped by prometheus and presented on grafana

Sure, and my point was that if you switch to using Kubernetes you still run Docker containers and Strimzi has all the components needed to make it work without you needing to mess with manually setting up JMX_OPTS variables, etc. It's open source project, too. My question was more about VMs/Compose, since there are better ways to setup a kafka cluster

No, Sorry, At this point I cant switch to any other components are modify my current setup. Should make my jmx exporter get the beans from Kafka so I can view this on grafana.

Using plain Compose / Docker run scripts isn't how you run things at scale, though (IMO). It's limited to a single machine. How are you planning on running a highly available Kafka cluster, assuming that VM goes down? And does Azure really matter at all for the question? You should be able to reproduce this JMX exporter question on any system (it doesn't need to scrape a public IP)

I understand your comment. But I am building a test setup for a quick demo. hence I do not need high availability at this time but I get your point. I looked up Strimzi as you suggested.. I found some pluggable prometheus exporter that I can just plug it to my kafka broker to export metrics to prometheus.. is that what you meant in your eaarlier comment?

It's meant to be ran in Kubernetes (which can still be used in one machine) . I'm not sure it'll just connect with any broker

Have you tried following any guides such as this? https://computingforgeeks.com/monitor-apache-kafka-with-prometheus-and-grafana/

interesting to see that I can install jmx exporter itself into my kafka installation. But for now I have use Kafka-exporter and it works well. But i would still like to know what is this error that I face when using a external jmx exporter alongside my kafka. why Kafka's jmx beans are not fetched at JMX Exporter via RMI.

Kafka-Exporter isn't the same as JMX Exporter. It has different metrics. Have you tried not using the public IP? Your monitoring addresses should all be internal to Azure network. Use a hostname within the VNET or a private IP
